# The mute light on my laptop just stays off

Tags: sound

I am pretty new in the Linux world and I do not have that much experience. I have got an HP Laptop of the 15-series. The device number is 9YP07EA. So, my problem is, the muting light indicator on the muting button does not work, but it mutes the device and I could not find any helpful tutorials or guides for this problem. This does not happen in windows, it only happens in ubuntu. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Edit 1: I am using ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: Hi @David, thank you for asking, I just edited the question.